# Set `__version__` of module from a file when configuring setuptools using `setup.cfg` without `setup.py`

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I’m following [PyPA](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/)’s current guidance to use only `setup.cfg` without `setup.py` for configuring metadata when building a package for distribution. (“[Static metadata (`setup.cfg`) should be preferred. Dynamic metadata (`setup.py`) should be used only as an escape hatch when absolutely necessary. `setup.py` used to be required, but can be omitted with newer versions of `setuptools` and `pip`.](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata)”)

To be concrete, I’m working with the following directory/file structure:

```
my-project/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src/
│   └── my_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── my_module.py
└── tests/
```

(If you’re unfamiliar with this structure that has a `src/` directory intermediating between the project directory and the import-package directory, it’s the structure given in the [Packaging Python Projects tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#a-simple-project) and argued for by [Ionel Cristian Mărieș](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) and [Mark Smith](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxfbdPcyxLVokUw4w9ug1bhAAqCIeLSA8v), et al. See also § “[Using a `src/` layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout)” in  [Configuring setuptools using `setup.cfg` files](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html).)

I had been successfully specifying the version number in `setup.cfg` simply with:

```
[metadata]
version = "0.0.1"
```

However, PyPA et al. have discussed the concept of “[single-sourcing the package version](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/),” which basically means AFAICT moving the definition of the version outside of `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` to (a) make it more broadly accessible by other tools and (b) put the definition of the version into a file that’s within the import-package directory (viz., `my-project/src/my_package`) and therefore installed with the code. (Admittedly, my use case is so simple there may be little benefit to moving the definition outside `setup.cfg`, but I’m drawn to exploring best practices—perhaps irrationally so. )

In particular, much of the discussion includes defining a separate file, e.g., `__version__.py`, `version.py`, or even `VERSION`, to hold the version information. Moreover, this version file would be located at (a) the root of the import package, e.g., of `my_package`:

```
path-to/project-directory/src/my_package/__version__.py
```

rather than at (b) the root of the `project-directory` where `setup.cfg` resides. (I deliberately hyphenate `project-directory` and use underscores in `my_package` to emphasize that PyPI [normalizes underscores, etc. to hyphens in project names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/#normalized-names), whereas those normalized names would be illegal as the name of a Python package.)

The overwhelming majority of the discussion about single-sourcing the version number takes place in the context of defining metadata dynamically using `setup.py` rather than statically using only `setup.cfg`. And that part of the discussion that does address using static metadata (i.e., `setup.cfg` without `setup.py`) (e.g., [Configuring setuptools using setup.cfg files](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html)) raises as many questions as it answers. In particular, it’s silent on how to configure the separate version-specifying file and how the various files involved interrelate.

What are the options, and how precisely do you configure the appropriate files, to specify the version of a package/module when you specify the project metadata statically with `setup.cfg`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the course of formulating the above question, I incrementally solved it to find three methods that work:

- Two methods use the `attr:` special directive in `setup.cfg`. Of these:

  - One puts the version number directly in the package’s `__init__.py` file.
  - The other puts the version number in a separate file (`__version__.py`) and then `__init__.py` imports the version string from that separate file.
- The third method uses instead the `file:` special directive in `setup.cfg`.

  - This reads the separate version-specifying file (`VERSION`) directly and doesn’t involve the package’s `__init__.py` file at all.

In light of these three possibilities, I re-present the directory/file structure with the addition of the two version-specifying files `__version__.py` and `VERSION`:

```
my-project/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src/
│   └── my_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __version__.py
│       ├── VERSION
│       └── my_module.py
└── tests/
```

Of course, you’d have at most one of those two files, depending on which of the three solutions you chose to implement.

## The two `attr:` special-directive solutions

In both of the solutions using the `setup.cfg`’s `attr:` special-directive, `setup.cfg` obtains the import package’s version from the import package’s `__version__` attribute. (When you import `some_package` that has a version, use `dir(some_package)` and you’ll see that it has a `__version__` attribute.) Now you see the connection here between the `attr:` name of the special directive and our goal.

The key task: how to assign the `__version__` attribute to `my_package`?

We assign the `__version__` attribute, either directly or indirectly, using the package’s `__init__.py` file, which already exists (assuming you have a traditional package rather than a [namespace package](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages), which is outside the scope of this answer).

### The snippet in `setup.cfg` that is common in both Method A and Method B

In both of these `attr:` special-directive solutions, the configuration of the `setup.cfg` file is the same, with the following snippet:

```
[metadata]
name = my-project
version = attr: my_package.__version__
```

To be clear, here the `.__version__` references an *attribute*, not a file, subpackage, or anything else.

Now we branch depending on whether the version information goes directly into `__init__.py` or instead into its own file.

### Method A: Put the assignment into the package’s `__init__.py` file

This method doesn’t use a separate file for specifying the version number, but rather inserts it into the package’s `__init__.py` file:

```
# path-to/my-project/src/my_package/__init__.py
__version__ = '0.0.2'
```

Note two elements of the assignment:

- the left-hand side (`__version__`) corresponds to the `attr:` line in `setup.cfg` (`version = attr: my_package.__version__`)
- the [legitimate version string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#public-version-identifiers) on the right-hand side is a string enclosed by quotes.

We’re done with Method A.

### Method B: Put the assignment into a `__version__.py` file and import it in `__init__.py`

#### Create `__version__.py` and put the version string in it

We construct a new Python file and locate it at the same level as the import package’s `__init__.py` file.

We insert the exact same `__version__` directive that we inserted in `__init__.py` in Method A:

```
# my-project/src/my_package/__version__.py
__version__ = '0.0.2'
```

#### From within `__init__.py`, `import` `__version__` from `__version__.py`

In `__init__.py`, we do a relative import to access the `__version__` that was assigned in the separate file:

```
# path-to/my-project/src/my_package/__init__.py
from . __version__ import __version__
```

To unpack this a little…

- We’re doing a relative import, so we have to use the `from … import …` syntax. ([Absolute imports may use either the `import <>` or `from <> import <>` syntax, but relative imports may only use the second form](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).)
- The `.` [indicates a relative import, starting with the current package](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).
- The first occurrence of `__version__` refers to the “module” `__version__.py`.

  - This file name doesn’t have to be `__version__.py`. That’s just conventional. Whatever the filename is, however, it must match the name after `from .` (except that the `.py` is stripped off in the `from . import` statement).
- The second occurrence of `__version__` refers to the assignment statement inside of `__version__.py`.

  - I’m not sure whether this string *needs* to be `__version__`, but it certainly at a minimum needs to match the assignment statement.

We’re done with Method B.

## Method C: Using the `file:` special directive

### The separate file is populated differently

In this method, we use a separate file for the version number, as in Method B. Unlike Method B, we read the contents of this file directly, rather than importing it.

To prevent confusion, I’ll call this file simply `VERSION`. Like `__init__.py` and Method B’s `__version__.py`, `VERSION` is at the root level of import package. (See the directory/file diagram.) (Of course, in this method, you won’t have `__version__.py`.)

However, the contents of this `VERSION` file are much different than the contents of Method B’s `__version__.py`.

Here’s the contents of `my-project/src/my_package/VERSION`:

```
0.0.2
```

Note that:

- This file contains nothing but the *contents* of the version string itself. In particular, do *not* enclose this string in quotation marks!
- There’s also no assignment syntax going on; there’s no “`__version__ =` ” preamble to the assignment string.
- This isn’t even a Python file, so I didn’t include a comment string with the path to the file, because that would be enough to give the error `VERSION does not comply with PEP 440: # comment line`.

### `setup.cfg` is different than before

There are two points of note that distinguish `setup.cfg` in Method C from the `setup.cfg` that was common to both Methods A and B.

#### `setup.cfg` uses `file:` rather than `attr:`

In Method C, we use a different formulation in `setup.cfg`, swapping out the `attr:` special directive and replacing it with the `file:` special directive. The new snippet is:

```
[metadata]
name = my-project
version = file: src/my_package/VERSION
```

#### The file path to `VERSION` is relative to the *project directory*

Note the path to `VERSION` in the assignment statement: `src/my_package/VERSION`.

The relative file path to the `VERSIONS` file is relative to the root of the *project* directory `my-project`. This differs from Method B, where the relative import was relative to the import-package root, i.e., `my_package`.

We’re done with Method C.

## Pros and cons

Method A might be seen to have a virtue of needing no additional file to set the version (because, in addition to `setup.cfg`, which is needed in any case, Method A uses only `__init__.py`, which likewise already exists). However, having a separate file for the version number has its own virtue of being obvious where the version number is set. In Method A, sending someone to change the version number who didn’t already know where it was stored might take a while; it wouldn’t be obvious to look in `__init__.py`.

Method C might seem to have the advantage over Method B, because Method B requires modification to two files (`__init__.py` and `__version__.py`) rather than only one for Method C (`VERSION`). The only perhaps countervailing advantage of Method B is that its `__version__.py` is a Python file that allows embedded comments, which Method C’s `VERSION` does not.

Comment: Very detailed, thanks. It might be worth mentioning that with Method A and B to use the version number in your code you use `from my-package.__init__ import __version__`

Answer (score 1):

I use setuptools-scm to do this. Create a pyproject.toml file with the following contents:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2",
    "wheel",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
write_to = "path/to/_version.py"
fallback_version = "1.0.0"
```

When you install the package, this will result in setuptools creating the file `_version.py` where you told it to.

`_version.py` will have a variable in it called `version`. I read this into `__version__` in the main package `__init__.py`.

```py
# __init__.py
from ._version import version as __version__
```

I guess I'm assuming you're using git here. I don't know if it works for other scm tools. It works by reading the tag information out of the git metadata. So your project needs to contain tags with pip-compatible version strings.